# Cannot resolve symbol

Tags: java, android

Почему IDE выделяет красным `spinnerSecond` после аннотации? Я же прописал его в `onCreate()`

```
public class SelectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_selection);

    Spinner spinnerBase = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.baseSpinner);

    Spinner spinnerSecond = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.secondSpinner);
    Spinner spinnerThird = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.thirdSpinner);
    spinnerBase.setOnItemSelectedListener((AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener) this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View itemSelected, final int position, long selectedId){
    parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    if (position==1){
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
                (this, R.array.forPress, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinnerSecond.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
    else if (position==2){
```

Comment: потому что пришло время узнать о областях видимости переменных

Comment: блин, вот лопух,  спс